Clarification regarding flexible array member access
From C23 §6.7.2.1(20):

[...] when a . (or ->) operator has a left operand that is a (pointer to) a structure with a flexible array member and the right operand names that member, it behaves as if that member were replaced with the longest array (with the same element type) that would not make the structure larger than the object being accessed; the offset of the array shall remain that of the flexible array member, even if this would differ from that of the replacement array.

I am not sure I understand the last sentence. Why would the offset of the replacement array differ from that of the flexible array member (FAM)? If the replacement array has the same element type as that of the FAM, then wouldn't it have the same alignment as the FAM and, therefore, the same offset as the FAM?

Re “wouldn't it have the same alignment as the FAM and, therefore, the same offset as the FAM?”: That is not a requirement of the C standard.

Thanks @EricPostpischil, I thought it would follow from the requirement that the replacement array has the same element type as the FAM. I am still confused as to why this is not the case.

While I am not aware of any, a C implementation could decide to make the last member of a structure “right-aligned.” E.g., given four-byte aligned int and eight-byte aligned double, a C implementation could make struct { double d; int i[5]; } eight bytes of d, four padding bytes, then 20 bytes of i, while struct {double d; int i[6]; } would be eight bytes of d, no padding bytes, then 24 bytes of i. Both of these align their members as required and use the same amount of space as traditional layout (minimum required padding before each member, then what is needed at end)…

… So, if they both use the same space and satisfy all the requirements, why prefer the traditional layout over this right-aligned layout? Another hypothetical possibility is that a C implementation might use a different alignment for structure members that are large. E.g., if a member is int i[1024];, then align it to a cache line instead of just to four bytes as would be done for int i[3];. Then the rule about flexible array member offsets is needed to account for that.

@EricPostpischil: your arguments sounds correct, but right aligning a Flexible Array Member looks weird ;-)

Thanks @EricPostpischil, I like the cache example.

The C standard doesn't describe much detail how padding is laid out in a structure.  The only requirement is that there is no padding at the beginning.
Specifically, section 6.7.2.1p17 of the C23 standard states:

... There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not
at its beginning

And 6.7.2.1p19 states:

There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union

So for example, given the following structs:
struct foo1 {
    int i;
    double d;
    int f[3];
};

struct foo2 {
    int i;
    double d;
    int f[];
};

The compiler would be free to lay them out as follows:
// total size: 32 bytes
struct foo1 {
    int i;                // offset 0
    // 4 bytes padding
    double d;             // offset 8
    // 4 bytes padding
    int f[3];             // offset 20
};

// total size: 16 bytes + flexible array member
struct foo2 {
    int i;                // offset 0
    // 4 bytes padding
    double d;             // offset 8
    int f[];              // offset 16
};

Then if you created an instance of struct foo2 with 3 flexible array members as follows:
struct foo2 *x = malloc(sizeof(struct foo2) + 3 * sizeof(int));

The "replacement array" in this case would have type int[3] as that is the maximum allowed given the actual object allocated.
The offset of x->f would be required to be 16 as per the passage you marked in bold, even though an instance of struct foo1, whose f member is the same size as the replacement array above, would have that member at offset 20.

Thanks @dbush, but why would the offset of foo1.f have any bearing on that of foo2.f? foo1 and foo2 are distinct types.

They're distinct types, but a compiler would be free to treat them the same with regard to padding if not for the rule you quoted.
